# PostGIS ST_LineMerge ignoring z coordinate?

Tags: postgis

It seems that the function `ST_LineMerge` in PostGIS ignores the z-coordinate.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Examples:

(a) This works correctly as the x, y and z-coordinates of the end points match (1, 1, 0):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_LineMerge(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRINGZ((0 0 0,1 1 0),(1 1 0,2 2 0))')
    )
);

LINESTRING Z (0 0 0,1 1 0,2 2 0)
```

(b) In the example below, they last points do not match, and yet the the line segments are joined by `ST_LineMerge`. The result is the same as the previous example even though the z-coordinate of the first point of the second line segment is different.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_LineMerge(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRINGZ((0 0 0,1 1 0),(1 1 9,2 2 0))')
    )
);

LINESTRING Z (0 0 0,1 1 0,2 2 0)
```

This is wrong surely!

Version info (on Windows 10):

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.6.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong. all that is, ([ST_LineMerge](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html)) is returns a (set of) LineString(s) formed by sewing together the constituent line. So if the first coordinates of the second set are not identical as the last coordinate of the first set, it will return the same geometry of the first set.

Comment: @User2009: No, that's not correct. For example, if I change it so the y-coordinates are different but the z-coordinates are the same, the result is not a single linestring.`SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_LineMerge(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRINGZ((0 0 0,1 1 0),(1 9 0,2 2 0))')
    )
);` This returns `MULTILINESTRING Z ((0 0 0,1 1 0),(1 9 0,2 2 0))`.

Comment: Yeah it will give you both segments but not the merged one ([as refer here in the example](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html)), it says (If can't be merged - original MULTILINESTRING is returned)

Comment: That's exactly my point. If the two segments don't match they should not be merged. So why in my example (b) does it merge the two lines segments when the z-coordinates are different? It should return the original MULTILINESTRING but it doesn't - it merges them to a single LINESTRING.

Comment: ST_LineMerge is not listed in the [Postgis functions that support 3D list](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_3D_Functions), so this is expected behaviour. There may be a workaround using combinations of other functions that do support 3D coordinates.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Thanks, I had not seen that list. That explains it then. Not ideal for me of course, but at least explainable. Cheers.